# How to handle the exception when a HashMap returns NULL

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have a method as follows; It does some computation and then returns a HashMap.

```
public Map<Integer, Animal> method() {
     // do some computation
     returns hashMap;
    }
```

1.) What hapence if the hash map returns `null`, will i get an null pointer exception ? and if so should i handle it as

```
public Map<Integer, Animal> method() throws{
```

So that the calling method will handle it ?

Answer (score 2):

When you get a object check if it is null... If a null value is not intended you can specify that it may throw a `NullPointerException` just for documentation since it's a `RunTimeException` and all `RuntimeExceptions` can be trown anywhere.

You can also do a:

```
try{
    /* calculate */
}
catch(NullPointerException e){
    /* process exception */
}
```

to process when a `NullPointerException` happens, so you can revert the actions or close the resources or throw a more descriptive exception...

For example:

```
try{
    Type o = (Type) map.get(key);
    o.doSomething();
}
catch(NullPointerException e)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Null values are not accepted!", e);
}
```

Comment: In a nutshell, does this mean i can leave `method()` as it is, and return an empty hashMap instead ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not give null pointer exception because you are just returning `HashMap`. In calling method before doing any operation on returned `HashMap` make sure to check that returned value is not null.

Answer (score 1):

A `NullPointerException` occurs when you try to use the `.` on a `null` variable. For example:

```
String s = null;
char c = s.charAt(0); // Tries to access null, throws NPE
```

Another place a `NullPointerException` can occur is when you try to unbox a `null` wrapper:

```
Integer integer = null;
int i = integer; // Tries to unbox null, throws NPE
```

These are the only ways you can ever get a `NullPointerException`. Well, unless someone explicitly throws one:

```
throw new NullPointerException();
```

But you should *never* do that. Throw an `IllegalArgumentException` instead.

That being said, returning `null` from a method won't produce a `NullPointerException`. However, using the `.` on the result of that method when it *does* return `null` can:

```
Map<Integer, Animal> map = method();
map.get(20); // Throws NPE if method() returns null
```

To fix this, you use a `null`-check:

```
Map<Integer, Animal> map = method();
if (map != null)
    map.get(20); // Never throws NPE
```

Note that we can still use `map` as a *reference*, but we can't *access* it since it's `null`. That's the distinction it seems you're missing.

**Edit for your comment**

> So you are suggesting that I should leave `method()` as it is (without exception handling) and check it from the calling function?

That's one possible option. Another is throw an exception to indicate that it's `null` if it's not supposed to be.

The big question is, is it *allowed* to be `null`? If it is, then leave `method()` as is, and check if it's `null` when you call it like I have above. Indicate in your Javadoc comments that this method may return `null`.

If it *isn't* allowed to return `null`, then when the method is called, either create the `Map` or throw an exception. You can even create the map only when it's `null` (this is called [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)):

```
public Map<Integer, Animal> method() {
    if (hashMap == null)
        hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Animal>();
    return hashMap;
}
```

If your `hashMap` is being created somewhere else, so this method shouldn't be called until after that other place created it (called a [precondition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition)), then you should throw an exception. For precondition violations, I usually use `IllegalStateException`:

```
public Map<Integer, Animal> method() {
    if (hashMap == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Must call otherMethod() to initialize hashMap before calling this method.");
    return hashMap;
}
```

Comment: So you are suggesting that i should leave `method()` as it is (without exception handling) and check it from the calling function ?